# Problem with facebook like button on some pages, but not others

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-like

If I click the like button on this page: http://ratemymechanic.us/site/mechanic_info/37, I get an error that this page requires tag `<meta property="og:image" ...>` - which it has.

If I click the like button on this page: http://ratemymechanic.us/site/mechanic_info/4, it works fine.

What is the problem that it is not working on the first page? I am populating the title and url of the meta tags dynamically with php, but the image tag I currently have hard coded in.

Comment: Both pages work fine in FF4 here...

Comment: Now it just worked for me too in chrome. I wonder if it's a timing/sync/cache issue?

Comment: I still get an error when trying to like this page though: http://ratemymechanic.us/site/mechanic_info/9

Comment: No error on that page either.

Comment: I'm using FF 4.0.1 and I get the error.

Comment: Not sure what the deal is. Seems to work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very good tool for debugging the Open Graph protocol is the [Facebook URL Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/).